# vue.js:Is there a way to inject a component into other component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to vue, and what i would really want to do is to have the possibility to insert a component into another component, without knowing the name of the component.

What i can do, at the moment, is to create a component "componentA" in which i make use of another component "componentB".

However, my goal would be to have componentA declare that it wants to use some component, when it doesn't yet know the component's name. Then, obtain the component's reference through props (or wherever) and use it.

In the same way that, through props, a component can obtain information without knowing what it's gonna be, i would like to know if the component can receive another component and make use of it, without knowing what the component is gonna be.

Is there a way to achieve this in vue.js?

**Edit**: It can be done by using Dynamic Components. Thank for providing the answer in the comments.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I need to figure it out, but i think that it does what i want. Thank you.